# Combine data from different parts of the store tree and dispatch actions?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have data that is read from different endpoints, and is dependent on each other, as if they were relational tables.

An example response from endpoint `users_country`, for example, could be

```
[
  { id: 4, first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Jones", country: "Brazil" },
  { id: 7, first_name: "Peter", last_name: "Martinez", country: "US" },
  { id: 14, first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Roland", country: "France" }
]
```

This is stored in the redux store by a reducer, suppose it's called countries.

Then I also receive data from a ws, handled by a usersPets reducer. I get new row every time a user gets a pet (this is a fictional example)

I get an object `{ id: 4, first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Jones", pet: "cat" }`, and add it to the usersPets data in the redux store

```
[      
  { id: 104, first_name: "Jesus", last_name: "Martin", pet: "cat" },
  { id: 4, first_name: "Mary", last_name: "Jones", pet: "cat" }
]
```

Then there is an endpoint `user_details` which is called by user id that gives details for a specific user, that returns more detailed data for that user.

For each of the ids in the redux store, I have to call this endpoint id by id, but only once per id.

Where would I make this call and how to architect this?

I would need to store the ids for which the `user_details` has already been called separately? how do I do that from the reducer? I can't

Should I handle this from the actions? Dispatch an action every time I have a new row for `users_country` and `users_that_have_pets`?

I don't understand how to handle this problem

I think what I need to know is if there is a place in the code outside the components where A) I have access to the store, and know when it updates, and B) can dispatch an action.

Comment: Are you using any middleware libraries for redux e.g. [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)? These "side-effects" are easier to implement using one of the above libraries. For example, by using redux-saga you can execute a function which can fetch additional data if this doesn't exist in the redux store.

Comment: @Christiaan I am using redux-thunk. I am not expert in this

Comment: @Christiaan I was advised to use https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk but I don't understand it at all